# Determine the destination page on redirect

Tags: asp.net

My question is pretty straight:-

When navigating from a page "page1.aspx" to any another page. I want to determine that **another-page's name in any server side event of the page1.aspx.

thanks.

Comment: How you are navigating? anyways, which page you are redirecting to is static.

Comment: You can change the targeturl of any hyperlink server side as long as it has runat="server"

Comment: It's may be strait, but not enough...How do you navigate? Why do you think page1 will be hit when you navigate from the client to any other page?

Answer (score 0):

You can set session variable on every page load and similarly before setting the currrent page name check the value of session to know the previous page name. You can also use query string but while redirecting you will need to append the page name in query string,

Comment: Need to know the called page name in the calling page itself. Your answer is for the opposite case, so not applicable.

Comment: And why do you so sure page1.aspx will be hit at all while navigating?